# my mysql table doesnt get refreshed what to do

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

after inseet/delete /update i have to manually update the page until i see the result..why? how can i solve this problem

```
   if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']=='submitted') {
 if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $selected = $_POST['selected'];
    for ($i=0; $i<$columncount;$i++){
    $value[$i] = $_POST[$name[$i]];
     foreach ($selected as $j)
    mysql_query ("UPDATE $tablename set $name[$i]='".$value[$i][$j]." 'WHERE $name[0]=".$value[0][$j]);}
}
```

its reading table value from a form and updating

Comment: still not getting exactly what is the issue.... what do u mean by manually updating....

Comment: check for the validity of the mysql queries. print the query before executing and try executing them in phpmyadmin or sql console.
also check whether you are executing select queries before update queries

Answer (score 1):

Because you update the database after displaying the table.

In other words, you fetch the values, display them, then update them. To fix this just put the above code above the table display.

Comment: i tried but the says post value doesnt recognizes the index and doesnt recognizes it at all

Comment: This happens to me from time to time, and it usually is caused by the problem you described. It's especially likely if the page always shows the updated value after exactly one reload.

Comment: @user1552802 : What do you mean by "post values doesn't recognize the index", please be more precise. Is it a PHP error ?

Answer (score 0):

Other than the obvious [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities that are just begging to get your server pwn3d,  you have no error handling whatsoever on your query - you're assuming it succeeded. Why not take the extra 2 seconds to try and handle the possibility that your query might actually have a syntax error?

```
$result = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Hope it will work

```
mysql_query ("UPDATE ".$tablename." set ".$name[$i]."='".$value[$i][$j]."' WHERE ".$name[0]."='".$value[0][$j]."';");}
```